# Write down the character of W.

Tags: representation-theory

[image]

I have done part (ii)(a) of this but I am stuck with how to do part (b) write down the character of W, and I have yet to try (c) I don't really understand the tensor product.

Many thanks!

Comment: You might want to type up your question.  [Here is a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It will make it more legible as well as preserve the privacy of Emily, who is apparently quite smelly. :)

Comment: have changed it, couldn't work out how to crop my screen capture but have done now.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\in{\rm End}(V)$ and $B\in{\rm End}(W)$ then there is an endomorphism $A\otimes B\in{\rm End}(V\otimes W)$ which acts on pure tensors as $(A\otimes B)(v\otimes w)=Av\otimes Bw$. We have ${\rm tr}(A\otimes B)={\rm tr}(A){\rm tr}(B)$. This tells you how to write down the character of $U_5\otimes U_6$. Since characters determine representations, to decompose $U_5\otimes U_6$ as a direct sum of irreducible representations, it suffices to write its character as an integer sum of irreducible characters. By viewing the characters as linearly independent vectors, this becomes a basic linear algebra problem.

Comment: so its tr($U_5$)tr($U_6$)? but what are those matrices?

Comment: @user150068 Who said anything about matrices? The values of one character are in one row, the values of the other character are in another row, and you need to multiply the values together to create a new row. This shouldn't be hard.

Comment: thats where i got confused, you're taking the trace of something though?

Comment: Yes, that's how characters are defined...

Comment: yeah I know but how do you use that if there are no matrices? I don't understand how that tells us how to write the character the question asks for.

Comment: If you know the values of ${\rm tr}(A)$ and ${\rm tr}(B)$ then you know the value of ${\rm tr}(A\otimes B)$ in terms of those two numbers. I just gave you the formula: again, it's ${\rm tr}(A\otimes B)={\rm tr}(A){\rm tr}(B)$. It doesn't matter whether or not you know the matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: oh of course, sorry! so is it just $\chi_5$ multiplied by $\chi_6$?

Comment: Multiplied componentwise, yes.

Comment: I can see it, but I am unsure how to write it?

Comment: The same way the other characters are written.

Comment: Is it just $\chi_5\chi_6$? its a 3 mark question?

Comment: Yes, $\chi_{U_{\large 5}\otimes U_{\large 6}}(x_i)=\chi_5(x_i)\chi_6(x_i)$ for $1\le i\le 6$.

Comment: So, W=$\chi_5(x_i)\chi_6(x_i)$ for 1≤i≤6

Comment: Then to find W as a sum of irreducible CQ modules for the next part of the question I thought I used the inner product to calculate the $a_i$, since $a_i$=<$\chi_W, \chi_i$> but I just wanted to check, do I use all 1 to 6 or just 5 and 6?

Comment: It's possible for $\chi_W$ to be a linear combination of $\chi_i$s in which $i$ isn't just $5$ or $6$, so you need to check all $i=1,\cdots,6$.

Comment: okay thats what I thought thanks